# C++ Object references in loop

Tags: c++, loops, object, memory, pointer-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Object references in loop cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939832/c-object-references-in-loop-cycle)

I'm trying to create different objects of the same type using a loop, and then storing a pointer to each specific object in a linked list. 
The problem is, each time an object is instanciate, its pointer return the same memory adress, wich doesn't allow me to differentiate each individual object in that list.

I'm trying to create different objects of the same type using a loop, and then storing a pointer to each specific object in a linked list. The problem is, each time an object is instanciate, its pointer return the same memory adress, wich doesn't allow me to differentiate each individual object in that list.

Any solution to that? Thanks

I have a function with the following:

```
    Data dt(10,10,2010);
int p=0;
ifstream fx;
fx.open("utilizadores.txt",ifstream::in);
if(!fx)
{cout << "FX. nao existe!" <<endl;}
string linha;
string nLugar;
int iD=1;

while(!fx.eof())
{
    getline(fx,linha,'\n');
    Utilizador* user;
    if(linha.find(',')==-1 && linha.size()>1)
    {
        cout<<"Entrou no vector"<<endl;
        string nlugar(linha.substr(0, linha.size()));
        nLugar=nlugar;

    }

      else
    {
        int inic=0;
        int pos=linha.find(',',inic);
        string nick(linha.substr(inic,pos-inic));
        pos++;
        inic=pos;
        pos=linha.find(',',inic);
        string email(linha.substr(inic,pos-inic));
        user=new Utilizador(dt,iD,nick,email);
        cout<<&user<<endl;
        cout<<user->clone()<<endl;
        }
    fx.close();
    }
```

The linked list is declared in the class statement

Any solution to that?
Thanks

Comment: This is not supposed to happen unless you `delete` the object after creating it or some other bug.  Please post example code or we won't be able to help.

Comment: How are you instantiating the objects?

Comment: Code please.  Pushing instance variables onto a list is fine, pushing a pointer to instance variables sounds suspicious..

Answer (score 1):

```
    cout<<&user<<endl;
```

This does *not* print the address of the object, but the address of the *pointer* to the object. This pointer will always be in the same location on the stack for any given run of the program and thus will yield the same address.

Answer (score 0):

do you have something like?

```
std::list<myobjecttype*> lst;
for (..). 
{
   myobjecttype* a = new myobjecttype;
   lst.push_back(a);
}
```

Comment: Sorry guys, i'll have to create another topic because i can't seem to post the code using the small comment box
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939832/c-object-references-in-loop-cycle

Comment: @user1019880: You don't need to post it in the comment box.  Just edit your question ("edit" button on lower left of the question, right under the tags).

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't remember to edit...