# C++ Object references in loop cycle

Tags: c++, object, pointers, loops

I'm trying to create different objects of the same type using a loop, and then storing a pointer to each specific object in a linked list. The problem is, each time an object is instanciate, its pointer return the same memory adress, wich doesn't allow me to differentiate each individual object in that list.

Any solution to that? Thanks

I have a function with the following:

```
    Data dt(10,10,2010);
int p=0;
ifstream fx;
fx.open("utilizadores.txt",ifstream::in);
if(!fx)
{cout << "FX. nao existe!" <<endl;}
string linha;
string nLugar;
int iD=1;

while(!fx.eof())
{
    getline(fx,linha,'\n');
    Utilizador* user;
    if(linha.find(',')==-1 && linha.size()>1)
    {
        cout<<"Entrou no vector"<<endl;
        string nlugar(linha.substr(0, linha.size()));
        nLugar=nlugar;

    }

      else
    {
        int inic=0;
        int pos=linha.find(',',inic);
        string nick(linha.substr(inic,pos-inic));
        pos++;
        inic=pos;
        pos=linha.find(',',inic);
        string email(linha.substr(inic,pos-inic));
        user=new Utilizador(dt,iD,nick,email);
        cout<<&user<<endl;
        cout<<user->clone()<<endl;
        }
    fx.close();
    }
```

The linked list is declared in the class statement

Answer (score 3):

```
cout<<&user<<endl;
```

should be:

```
cout<<user<<endl;
```

&user is address of local variable Utilizador*, which remains the same. user variable value itself is the pointer you need, and it should be different on every iteration.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
cout<<&user<<endl;
```

prints the address of a pointer to an object. `user` is itself a pointer to the object you're creating. To print the address of your object, you meant to write

```
cout<<user<<endl;
```

Although it'll be a new object each time, the variable `user` is always in the same place. You can add the value of `user` to your list, and it will indeed be different each time.

Comment: And how do i add the value of user? Can you give an example?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't understanding your answer, english is not my native language...

I can't pass it by value, it has to be throw a pointer or memory reference

Comment: You don't seem to be adding anything to a list, anywhere, so I can't tell you exactly; but if you add "user", that will actually work just fine. Don't add "&user".

Answer (score 1):

"&user" return address of pointer, that contains references to objects.